# c# is it possible to trigger the button_click event with code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i dont want to click the button. instead, i just want to run the click event code. how would i do this?

Comment: The short answer is Yes!

Comment: If you have control of the code in the click event handler, the correct thing to do is to extract that code to a separate method that can be called from anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
button1_click(null, new EventArgs() );
```

Comment: And pray that the `sender` argument isn't used.

Comment: if you would like use sender than you simply put it instead of null.

Answer (score 9):

Option: use `PerformClick()`.

Take a look here: [How to: Call a Button's Click Event Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkkb40tf%28VS.90%29.aspx).

The advantage here is that the event behavior will be exactly the same as a real button click (as oposed of calling `button1_click` directly).

But none of this options is the best IMHO. If you need to call the event handler code, you need a new method! Just refactor the old `button1_click` into a new, standard method and call it from wherever you want.

Comment: +1: I've always assumed `PerformClick` is better than calling the button's handler directly, as the framework knows better than you do as to anything special it needs to do.  It also addresses Ben Voigt's comment about the `sender` argument.

Comment: +1 for refactor of the old button1_click, makes so much sense

Answer (score 2):

From inside or outside the `Form` where the `Button` is?  Simplest thing is to just call the function:

```
Button1_Click(Button1, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a keybd_event with p/invoke http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes do that by actually calling the event handler function, that's if I actually implemented it.
Literally call it like:

```
button1_Click(this, new EventArgs());
```